# Ubuntu 16.04 local mirror cannot be used for local updates

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I have a mirror which runs on 16.04. It's up to date (apt-mirror) and I have ...

```
root@netboot:/etc/apt# more mirror.list
############# config ##################
#
# set base_path    /var/spool/apt-mirror
#
# if you change the base path you must create the director below with write privileges
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  <running host architecture>
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     4
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############

# Xenial 64Bit Mirror - March 2017
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

apt-mirror runs as you would expect:

```
root@netboot:/etc/apt# apt-mirror
Downloading 206 index files using 4 threads...
Begin time: Thu Mar 30 19:58:18 2017
[4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Thu Mar 30 19:58:20 2017

Processing tranlation indexes: [TTTTT]

Downloading 1116 translation files using 4 threads...
Begin time: Thu Mar 30 19:58:20 2017
[4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Thu Mar 30 20:01:16 2017

Processing DEP-11 indexes: [DDDDD]

Downloading 50 dep11 files using 4 threads...
Begin time: Thu Mar 30 20:01:16 2017
[4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Thu Mar 30 20:01:18 2017

Processing indexes: [PPPPP]

0 bytes will be downloaded into archive.
Downloading 0 archive files using 0 threads...
Begin time: Thu Mar 30 20:01:21 2017
[0]...
End time: Thu Mar 30 20:01:21 2017

60.0 MiB in 96 files and 0 directories can be freed.
Run /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/clean.sh for this purpose.

Running the Post Mirror script ...
(/var/spool/apt-mirror/var/postmirror.sh)

/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/postmirror.sh

Post Mirror script has completed. See above output for any possible errors.
```

The can't open postmirror problem appears to be a known problem: [https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-mirror/+question/271255][1]

The mirror is complete as far as I can tell:

```
user@netboot:/etc/apt$ ls -l /var/www/ubuntu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Mar 30 19:12 /var/www/ubuntu -> /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
user@netboot:/etc/apt$ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         470M     0  470M   0% /dev
tmpfs                         98M  9.5M   89M  10% /run
/dev/mapper/vg_main-lv_root  112G   98G  9.4G  92% /
tmpfs                        488M     0  488M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        488M     0  488M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                         98M     0   98M   0% /run/user/1000
user@netboot:/etc/apt$ du -sh /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
96G /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
user@netboot:/etc/apt$ ls /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
dists  pool
user@netboot:/etc/apt$ ls /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/*
/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists:
xenial  xenial-backports  xenial-proposed  xenial-security  xenial-updates

/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool:
main  multiverse  restricted  universe
user@netboot:/etc/apt$ ls /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/*/*
/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial:
Contents-amd64.gz  InRelease  main  multiverse  Release  Release.gpg  restricted  universe

/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports:
Contents-amd64.gz  InRelease  main  multiverse  Release  Release.gpg  restricted  universe

/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-proposed:
Contents-amd64.gz  InRelease  main  multiverse  Release  Release.gpg  restricted  universe

/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security:
Contents-amd64.gz  InRelease  main  multiverse  Release  Release.gpg  restricted  universe

/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates:
Contents-amd64.gz  InRelease  main  multiverse  Release  Release.gpg  restricted  universe

/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main:
a  c  e  g  i  k  liba  libc  libe  libg  libi  libk  libm  libo  libq  libs  libu  libw  liby  m  o  q  s  u  w  y
b  d  f  h  j  l  libb  libd  libf  libh  libj  libl  libn  libp  libr  libt  libv  libx  libz  n  p  r  t  v  x  z

/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse:
3  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  liba  libc  libd  libf  libg  libm  libs  libt  libv  liby  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z

/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted:
b  i  n

/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe:
0  3  6  9  b  d  f  h  j  l     liba  libc  libe  libg  libi  libk  libm  libo  libq  libs  libu  libw  liby  m  o  q  s  u  w  y
2  4  7  a  c  e  g  i  k  lib3  libb  libd  libf  libh  libj  libl  libn  libp  libr  libt  libv  libx  libz  n  p  r  t  v  x  z
user@netboot:/etc/apt$
```

Now set /etc/apt/sources like this:

```
root@netboot:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse

root@netboot:~# apt-get update
Get:2 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:3 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:1 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Ign:5 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:8 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign:11 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign:14 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Get:5 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [501 kB]
Ign:6 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Get:7 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [202 kB]
Get:8 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [7,776 B]
Ign:9 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Get:10 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,548 B]
Get:11 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [450 kB]
Ign:12 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Get:13 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [172 kB]
Get:14 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [8,920 B]
Ign:15 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:16 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en [4,136 B]
Ign:6 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:6 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:9 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en
Ign:20 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:21 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:22 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en
Get:17 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages [4,672 B]
Ign:18 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Get:19 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en [3,200 B]
Get:20 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages [2,512 B]
Ign:21 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Get:22 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en [1,216 B]
Ign:18 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Err:18 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:21 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:24 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:25 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en
Ign:26 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign:29 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:30 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en
Ign:32 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:33 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:34 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en
Get:23 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [235 kB]
Ign:24 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Get:25 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [99.7 kB]
Get:26 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages [7,428 B]
Ign:27 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Get:28 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en [2,428 B]
Get:29 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [105 kB]
Ign:30 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Get:31 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en [54.4 kB]
Get:32 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [2,748 B]
Ign:33 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:34 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en [1,232 B]
Ign:24 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:27 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:30 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:33 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:24 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:27 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:30 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:33 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:35 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:36 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:37 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:38 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:39 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:40 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:41 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign:42 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:43 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:44 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:45 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en_GB
Ign:46 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Ign:47 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:48 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:49 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Ign:50 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en
Get:35 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,201 kB]
Ign:36 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Get:37 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_GB [426 kB]
Get:38 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en [568 kB]
Get:39 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages [8,344 B]
Ign:40 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Get:41 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en_GB [2,556 B]
Get:42 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en [2,908 B]
Get:43 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages [7,532 kB]
Ign:44 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Get:45 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en_GB [3,040 kB]
Get:46 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en [4,354 kB]
Get:47 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]
Ign:48 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:49 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en_GB [88.1 kB]
Get:50 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en [106 kB]
Ign:36 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:40 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:44 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:48 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:36 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:40 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:44 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:48 http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
Fetched 2,421 kB in 1s (1,619 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://netboot.domain.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Now try to install a package 'bc' for example:

```
root@netboot:~# apt-get install bc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bc
root@netboot:~#
```

It should be there...  http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/bc   and the files are present.

```
root@netboot:~# ls -ld /var/www/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 30 13:23 /var/www/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bc
root@netboot:~# ls -l /var/www/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bc
total 132
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 82552 Dec 11  2014 bc_1.06.95-9build1_amd64.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 46386 Dec 11  2014 dc_1.06.95-9build1_amd64.deb
```

Any pointers as to how I diagnose the problem?

Comment: Did you get a resolution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To summarise, it appears that the issue is the base OS of the netboot server - it's simply too old.

Ideally use an Ubuntu16 server to host the netboot image.

Or try this workaround to the problem which is that you can't install additional packages (using apt-get) because the i18n directories are missing on the netboot mirror. This script adds the missing i18n directories and gets the files from an Ubuntu repository. This should be run after apt-mirror.

/var/www/postmirror.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

## anything in this file gets run AFTER the mirror has been run
## put your custom post mirror operations in here ( like rsyncing the installer files and running clean.sh automaticly )

## Example of grabbing the extra translations and installer files from ubuntu ( note rsync needs to be installed
## and in the path for this example to work correctly )

# NOTE: This script should be run as root

#set -x

DISTS="xenial xenial-backports xenial-proposed xenial-security xenial-updates"
TAGS="restricted multiverse universe main"

SOURCE_ROOT=gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists
TARGET_ROOT=/var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/${SOURCE_ROOT}

for DIST in ${DISTS}
do
  for TAG in ${TAGS}
  do
    echo "Removing ${TARGET_ROOT}/${DIST}/${TAG}/i18n"
    rm -rf ${TARGET_ROOT}/${DIST}/${TAG}/i18n
    echo "Getting i18n folder from http://${SOURCE_ROOT}/${DIST}/${TAG}/i18n/"
    umask o+r,u+rw,g+rw
    wget -P${TARGET_ROOT}/${DIST}/${TAG}  -nH --cut-dirs=4 -r --reject "index.html*" --no-parent http://${SOURCE_ROOT}/${DIST}/${TAG}/i18n/
  done
done
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference from where you figured out the solution?

Comment: Worked for Bionic too. Replace Xenial with Bionic.